# convert each words into one list dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

Suppose a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j is a word ,not a single letter.

```
cate  word
apple [['a','b'],['c','d','e']]
pen   [['f','g','h'],['j']]
```

I want to get one list in `word` column.So the expected output should be `word_list =[u'a b c d e',u'f g h j']`

However,when I use the following code:

```
word_list =[]

for line in df['word']:
    for word in line:
        word_list.append(word)
```

So the output is not what I expected.

Comment: Can you print `df.word.dtype` and tell me what is shown? Or just look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One efficient solution would be using `np.concatenate` + `str.join`:

```
df['word'] = df.word.apply(np.concatenate).str.join(' ')    
df

    cate       word
0  apple  a b c d e
1    pen    f g h j

df.word.tolist()
['a b c d e', 'f g h j']
```

If `df['word']` is not a column of lists (but of *strings*), you'll need to convert it using `ast.literal_eval` (the safe eval):

```
import ast
df['word'] = df.word.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

The rest of the solution is the same.

Comment: I just fixed my bug.Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @user3849475 Accept an answer if it helped, thanks. Also, you can upvote all helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

flatten then `list` then `join` it

```
df.word=df.word.apply(lambda x : ' '.join(sum(x,[])))

df
Out[847]: 
    cate       word
0  apple  a b c d e
1    pen    f g h j

df.word.tolist()
Out[848]: ['a b c d e', 'f g h j']
```

Data input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cate": ['apple','pen'],'word':[[['a','b'],['c','d','e']],[['f','g','h'],['j']]]})
```

Comment: I had an error message,it said that ```TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list```

Comment: @user3849475 is the can you show me the result of `df.word.apply(type)` and doing this before my solution `df['word']=df['word'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: The result is list type.```0     <type 'list'>
1     <type 'list'>
 ```

Comment: @user3849475 make sure it is list of list not list of str .

Comment: It said ```Name: word, dtype: object```

Comment: @user3849475 I have attach the data I am used

Comment: @user3849475 you can try to convert it back to list of list

Comment: @user3849475 ok